# prove that exactly one player has a winning strategy - version of nim game

Tags: induction

**Game Description** : the game is between 2 players and start with a pile of 'n' balls and A = {a1,a2,...,ak} ⊆ {1,....,n} .

**Course of the game** : each player, in his turn, picks a ∈ A
balls from the pile.

**the loosing player** : the player that can't play on his turn, player cant play on his turn when the number of balls in the pile is smaller from the minimum number in A.

**the Task** : we have to prove that to every show of the problem n,A = {a1,...,ak}  only one one of the following happens :
1) the first player (the player play first) has a winning strategy .
2) the second player has an winning strategy.
the winning strategy of the winner is not depend on the choices of the looser.

**My Idea**  : I have tried to prove it with complete  induction, but i'm stuck in the step.

I've assumed that for every show of the game with  `k<n` balls the assert is holds and tried to show it  holds for a game with 'n' balls.

so, the first case is that the first player can choose  a ∈ A  balls such that the number of balls left in the pile is less then the minimum number in A and hence player 2 cant perform his turn and player 1 allways wins.

otherwise, for any number of balls a ∈ A that player 1 took from the pile, player 2 can perform his turn. in this case the induction assertion holds (because the number of balls is less then 'n' in the pile now) and player 1 or player 2 (exactly one of them) has winning strategy. i'm stuck here. I don't know how to show that for every a ∈ A that player1 picks the player with the winning strategy will be the same one. for example if player 1 picks a1=4 from A and the induction assert find that player2 is the the player that has a winning strategy, it will return the same answear when player1 chooses a2=5 from A.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The crucial point is that the game is impartial, that the options from a given position are the same for both players.  That allows you to categorize each number as an $N$ position, won by the next player or a $P$ position, won by the previous player.  Now $n$ is an $N$ position iff you can move to a $P$ position.